# Pyspark dataframe query to populate column values after joining

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

**Input Dataframe 1**

[image: Input Dataframe 1]

**Input Dataframe 2**

[image: Input Dataframe 2]

**Joined Dataframe from Input Dataframe 1 and 2**

[image: Joined Dataframe from Input Dataframe 1 and 2]

**Expected outcome**

[image: Expected outcome]

I have two input pyspark dataframes as shown.
I have to join these two dataframes and in the column names "field1" and "field2"- I need to populate values from the Dataframe 1 of the respective column names mentioned (as shown in the expected output dataframe.)

Comment: It is not populating the data2 values then in field1 column this way

Comment: What are you trying to achieve is not clear to me, how the values for field1 and field2 are assigned ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` and `otherwise` after joining `df1` and `df2`. To make things a little more generalizable, we can write a function that creates the when + otherwise statement for a given column.

```
def create_condition(col_name): 
    return F.when(
        F.col(col_name) == 'data1', F.col('data1')
    ).when(
        F.col(col_name) == 'data2', F.col('data2')
    ).otherwise(
        None
    )

df1.join(
    df2, on='common_column', how='inner'
).withColumn(
    "field1",
    create_condition("field1")
).withColumn(
    "field2",
    create_condition("field2")
)

+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+
|common_column|data1|data2|field1|field2|
+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+
|            A|    1|    2|     1|     2|
|            B|    3|    4|     4|     3|
|            C|    5|    6|     5|  null|
+-------------+-----+-----+------+------+
```